# How to specify another font size for IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts

Say I have a class which specifies a font size, color and may other properties:

.myFont
{
    color:#F00;
    font-familiy:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
}

So I apply this to a

tag and I want for IE7 and IE8 the size was 13px, NOT 15px. How I can do this easily.

EDIT:

**Is there any way whithout including any new .css file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a stylesheet that is only loaded by IE, e.g. using [this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/).

You can then override the font-size in the base stylesheet in the IE stylesheet.

Comment: About this I knew. Is there any way whithout including any new .css file?

Comment: It's an additional request for IE users, but so what?  Why can't you use an extra stylesheet?  You could use JavaScript to dynamically change styles for IE users, but that's nasty and bad practice.

Comment: OK! .myFont{  font-size:15px; font-size:13px\9;} should work for me no? But it effects also IE9. How can a avoid this?

Comment: The clean way to do different styles for different browsers is to use a separate stylesheet.  IMO everything else is going to be a nasty, unreliable hack.

Comment: But I have tried with separate one, even with ! important, but it does not override the existing style.

Comment: I mean I have two styleshits one is normal and one is for IE 8 and lower. I include the IE 8 and lower styleshit after the normal one, and several properties of several classes already defined in the normal styleshit I want to overwrite by giving a new value. Is this a right mechanism?

Comment: The way WordPress does this is the following:

<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/style.css">
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/ie8-and-down.css">
<![endif]-->

Comment: Yes, and then refering to my example, in style.css it would be .myFont { color:#F00; font-familiy:Arial; font-size:15px; } and in ie8-and-down.css it whould be .myFont { font-size:13px; } RIGHT?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). They allow you to specify different or additional CSS for different versions of IE browsers. Works in IE only. That is, only IE treats the comments specially. Others just treat them as comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use one common stylesheet for all browsers, you can use `BODY:last-child` prefix to filter browsers other than IE6/7/8. It's a standard pseudoclass that is just not supported in IE8 and lower, and thus is quite future proof while does not need for a separate stylesheet file to target IE8 and lower.

So you can first specify styles for all browsers *including* IE8 and lower, and then override it for modern browsers:

```css
.example {/* styles for all browsers */}

BODY:last-child .example {/*
    styles for browsers other than IE6/7/8.
*/}
```

Comment: Wow, this I did not know.  That's beautiful.  Thanks!